# Prove $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

> Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a connected, compact and orientable surface with positive gaussian curvature. Then, $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S^2}$.

It follows directly from *Gauss-Bonnect Theorem* that any surface satisfying these conditions is necessarily homeomorphic to a sphere. But how one can prove that, with those same conditions, there's a diffeomorphism between them ?

Thank's for any hint.

Comment: It seems you want to use the classification of surfaces anyhow, so why not use the classification of surfaces in the smooth rather than the continuous category (which usually precedes it anyway).

Comment: I was looking for some basic differential geometry result that guarantee this, but I didn't find any. But I find a result that two smooth (2 dimensional) surfaces are homeomorphic iff they are diffeomorphic. Is this te classification you're talking about ?

Comment: Do you know what is the Gauss map?

Comment: Yes. Maybe using the fact that $M$ is orientable and the Gauss map its sufficient to prove it ?

Comment: Yes. A gauss map is a mapping from your surface to $\mathbb S^2$. Would it happens to be a diffeomorphism?

Comment: You said it follows from Gauss-Bonnet that the surface is homeomorphic to a sphere. You didn't elaborate, so I assumed you were noting that Gauss-Bonnet tells you $\chi(M)>0$ and then there you quote a classification result saying that the only surface with positive Euler characteristic is a sphere. This claim is true in both the topological and the smooth case and the former is usually proven using the latter, so my point is that you may as well quote the latter result to immediately get that it's diffeomorphic to a sphere. If you want a different proof altogether, listen to Arctic Char.